# How to fix Android Studio missing configurations?

Tags: java, android-studio

Suddenly, I am missing some configurations in Android Studio IDE, so,  My projects don't work and I get many code errors.

Also when I try to create a new project I get a setup or config window, but I don't know what I have to setup or configure.

Here is the image Ie got when try creating a new project:

[image: create new project]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have errors in some of your android studio plugins, so you can go to settings -> search for plugins
After that uncheck all the red plugins.
and restart the android studio.

Hope it helps...